# What should I use to model a non-monotonic relationship with values between 0 and 1?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am trying to find a good model to fit to these curves:

[image]

[image]
They are relationship between the probability of a dispute escalating into war, and the number of disputes in the past ten years between those two countries.

I have been using probit regression because the predicted values are between 0 and 1, but I realized it might not be the best since probit is monotonic.

Some of the curves look like this, basically, there's a peak, and then it slopes downward kind of gradually.

I want non-monotonicity, and something that works for a dependent variable between 0 and 1.

Comment: a probit model with a quadratic term in "number of disputes" might work fine, i.e. `glm(escalation~poly(num_disputes,degree=2), family=binomial(link="probit"), data= ...)`

Comment: ah gotcha, so that looks like a quadratic cure normalized between 0 and 1?